# extract common methods from interfaces

Tags: java, oop

I have the following problem. There's an interface called e.g `UserExpactations` with a bunch of methods in a `builder-style` to verify some logic.

Looks like this:

```
interface UserExpectations {
    UserExpectations expectSuccessResponseFromApi;
    UserExpectations expectFailResponseFromApi;


    UserExpectations expectUserInDB;
    // more user-specific methods
}
```

As you can each method return `UserExpactations` so we can chain them together.

Now I need to add one more expectator class and there's some common logic, namely the first two methods.

So it's going to look like this:

```
interface OrderExpectations {

    // these are common to UserExpectations
    OrderExpectations expectSuccessResponseFromApi;
    OrderExpectations expectFailResponseFromApi;


    OrderExpectations expectOrderInCart;
    OrderExpectations expectOrderInDB;
    // some more order specific methods
}
```

I want to extract these common methods to abstract class or maybe another top level interface. And these methods should be implemented in one place. And each `expectators` should be aware of their implementation. But the problem is that each common methods should return a specific `*Expactations` type in order to keep that ability to chain methods.

Can't find a way how to implement this. Maybe is there a nice pattern which can help to facilitate this problem that I'm not aware of.
Any ideas?

**UPDATED:**

So I wanted to create an abstract Expecations which will contain common methods:

Like this:

```
abstract class CommonExpactations<T> {
    T expectSuccessResponseFromApi() {
        // do some logic and then return T
    }
    T expectFailResponseFromApi() {
        // do some logic and return T
    }
}
```

And not each implementation of *Expectations specific interface should also extend CommonExpactations in order to get access to the common methods.
But java doesn't allow to create a new object of type `T` in abstract class in order to chain some other methods in concrete implementations.

So for example,

```
UserExpectationsImpl implements UserExpectations extends CommonExpactations<UserExpectations>
```

Comment: Do it via generics, and have an `protected abstract T newInstance();` that is implemented by the subclasses.

Comment: You should post a [mcve] for your "update" (also note that there's a typo in the second method return type `T UserExpectations expectFailResponseFromApi`)

Answer (score 1):

How about with generics?

```
public interface Expecations<T> {
    T expectSuccessResponseFromApi();
    T expectFailResponseFromApi();
    ....

}


public interface UserExcpectations extends Expecations<User> {

}
```

Comment: UserExcpectations doesn't need to know anything about expectOrderInCart or expectOrderInDB. But in your example it does, and moreover I wanted to implement these common methods. So in this case each implementation of UserExcpectations and OrderExpectations will have an access to their implementation

Comment: @user3127896,  expectOrderInCart & expectOrderInDB are the methods in  OrderExpectations interface. Those are not common to UserExpectations  interface. No where UserExpectations   know about those methods.                                                                                        The objective is to abstract the common methods in UserExcpectations & OrderExpectations interfaces right? If yes, as per the suggested answer, have an Expectations interface and extend it in both the UserExcpectations & OrderExpectations interfaces

Comment: You are correct but the thing is that I wanted to have an implementation of those common methods, not just declaration in interface

Comment: I suggest you to use java8 interfaces with which you can provide default implementaions to the methods. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: yeah I know about default methods, but the thing is that in order to implement those common methods I'll need to inject other objects and I can't do it in interface. That's why I was looking how to implement it using abstract class.

Comment: Try with anonymous object creation of abstract class. Will share the sample object creation code snippet in answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133211/discussion-between-nasreen-md-and-user3127896).

Answer (score 0):

Try with anonymous object creation of abstract class.

```
abstract class CommonExpactations<T> {
     T expectSuccessResponseFromApi() {
         // do some logic and then return T
     }
    T expectFailResponseFromApi() {
       // do some logic and return T
    }
}
```

In Child interfaces of CommonExpectations, say UserExpectations

```
CommonExpectations ce = new CommonExpectations<UserExpectations>(){

   //provide abstract method implementations
}
```

Comment: what's the point? Implementation should be placed in one place rather than in each child interface